# How to install AIR Plugin for Aptana Studio?

Tags: air, adobe, aptana

I'm trying to follow these directions to install the Adobe AIR plugin for Aptana:

http://www.aptana.com/products/air/install

But my Aptana Studio 3 Eclipse Plugin doesn't seem to have any options to install Plugins:

https://img.skitch.com/20120222-8u8qqf9sibxxiaagdp7qtbmr4u.jpg

How do you install this plugin now?

Answer (score 1):

The Adobe Air plugin is currently not supported in Aptana Studio 3.

Answer (score 1):

You can try to go and install Eclipse Plug-in Version of Aptana Studio into Eclipse, and then try to install this AIR plugin with in Software Install option in Eclipse IDE.

And Go to Help > Install New Software. Then on the Install screen, click the 'Available Software Sites' link. Then Enable the air site. When you are back on the Install screen, choose the air option from the Work with drop-down. From there you can install the Air 2.0 plugin

And did you read that here http://www.aptana.com/products/air/install ?
https://i.stack.imgur.com/o06Do.png

Answer (score 1):

Folks, I have some ***news***!!!

To we be able to install the Adobe Air plugin on the Aptana 3, we have to **follow those steps**:

- Go to **Help** > **Install/Update New Software**
- Click in **Add** (to add a new repository)
- Give any name you most like (ex: Air)
- put this address on the url field: **http://update.aptana.com/install/air**
- Press **OK**
- Select you new repo and install it.

**Enjoy! (;**

*[ I just figure it out today when I was mad re-installing the old aptana, then I saw the link from where the old one get the plugin, and I just add this link to the new version, and eureka!! ]*